# VBA to change links using cell references that contain old and new file path

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA and running into roadblock. Trying to have VBA edit two links in workbook. The two linked workbooks, Trend and Detail, are linked.

The current and new file paths for these two links are in cells D1 through D4 of the workbook. Running  into a run-time error ‘1004’, “Method ChangeLink of Object_Workbook failed.

Here is my current VBA, which is returning run-time error ‘1004’, “Method ChangeLink of Object_Workbook failed. When debugging, it is pointing to the first change link VBA.

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
    Dim oldTrendlink As String
    Dim newTrendlink As String
    Dim oldDetaillink As String
    Dim newDetaillink As String
    
oldTrendlink = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro").Range("D1").Value
newTrendlink = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro").Range("D2").Value

oldDetaillink = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro").Range("D3").Value
newDetaillink = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro").Range("D4").Value
    
ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=oldTrendlink, NewName:=newTrendlink, Type:=xlExcelLinks
    
ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=oldDetaillink, NewName:=newDetaillink, Type:=xlExcelLinks

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you share what's in *D1:D4*?

Answer (score 0):

### Link to a Different Workbook

**Basic**

```vb
Sub LinkToDifferentWorkbook()
    
    Const OLD_PATH As String = "C:\Test\Test1.xlsx"
    Const NEW_PATH As String = "C:\Test\Test2.xlsx"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim lsArr: lsArr = wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    
    If IsEmpty(lsArr) Then
        MsgBox "No Excel link sources found.", vbCritical
    Else
        If Len(Dir(NEW_PATH)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "The path """ & NEW_PATH & """ doesn't exist.", _
                vbCritical
        Else
            If IsError(Application.Match(OLD_PATH, lsArr, 0)) Then
                MsgBox "This workbook is not linked to """ & OLD_PATH & """.", _
                    vbCritical
            Else
                wb.ChangeLink OLD_PATH, NEW_PATH, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
                MsgBox "The workbook is now linked to """ & NEW_PATH & """.", _
                    vbInformation
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**Your Case**

```vb
Sub UpdateLinks()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim lsArr: lsArr = wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    
    If IsEmpty(lsArr) Then
        MsgBox "No Excel link sources found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Macro")
    
    ' Trend
    
    Dim OldTrendlink As String: OldTrendlink = ws.Range("D1").Value
    Dim NewTrendlink As String: NewTrendlink = ws.Range("D2").Value
    
    If Len(Dir(NewTrendlink)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path """ & NewTrendlink & """ doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical
    Else
        If IsError(Application.Match(OldTrendlink, lsArr, 0)) Then
            MsgBox "This workbook is not linked to """ & OldTrendlink & """.", _
                vbCritical
        Else
            wb.ChangeLink OldTrendlink, NewTrendlink, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
            MsgBox "The workbook is now linked to """ & NewTrendlink & """.", _
                vbInformation
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Detail
    
    Dim OldDetaillink As String: OldDetaillink = ws.Range("D3").Value
    Dim NewDetaillink As String: NewDetaillink = ws.Range("D4").Value
    
    If Len(Dir(NewDetaillink)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path """ & NewDetaillink & """ doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical
    Else
        If IsError(Application.Match(OldDetaillink, lsArr, 0)) Then
            MsgBox "This workbook is not linked to """ & OldDetaillink & """.", _
                vbCritical
        Else
            wb.ChangeLink OldDetaillink, NewDetaillink, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
            MsgBox "The workbook is now linked to """ & NewDetaillink & """.", _
                vbInformation
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```